# Laravel get one to many with limit by DB query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a products table that is connected through model_has_attachments with attachments table. I need to connect first attachment to each product record thought the query builder, but for some reason it just give me few records with model_has_attachments ids and rest is the null

my query builder look as:

```
$products = DB::table('products')->
leftJoin(DB::raw('(select `model_id`, `attachment_id` from model_has_attachments where model_has_attachments.model_id = id) as model_has_attachments'), 'model_has_attachments.model_id', 'products.id')->
leftJoin('attachments', 'model_has_attachments.attachment_id', '=', 'attachments.id')->
            select('products.id', 'products.square', 'products.height', 'products.address', 'products.rooms', 'products.title', 'products.description', 'model_has_attachments.model_id as id_model', 'model_has_attachments.attachment_id')->
            where([
            ['products.deleted_at', '=', null],
        ]);
```

I've tried to add `limit = 1` in the `DB::raw` but it just give me the first record of the products table, not a joined table. Can you tell me why?

I also tried different approach, but it takes all the record of attachments which result duplicate products records if product has more than one attachment. I also have tried to add `->limit(1)` at the end but it just ignores the method.

```
leftJoin('model_has_attachments', function ($join) {
    $join->on('products.id', '=', 'model_has_attachments.model_id')->where('model_has_attachments.model_type', '=', Product::class);
})->
``
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//try this

$products = Product::leftJoin('model_has_attachments', 'products.id', '=', 'model_has_attachments.model_id')
    ->leftJoin('attachments', 'attachments.id', '=', 'model_has_attachments.attachment_id')
    ->addSelect('products.*', 'attachments.id as attachment_id')
    ->where('attachments.is_active',1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hold on, it seems i was blind. It still gives copies of the products if attachments is more than one

Comment: `$products = Product::leftJoin('model_has_attachments', 'products.id', '=', 'model_has_attachments.model_id')
    ->leftJoin('attachments', 'attachments.id', '=', 'model_has_attachments.attachment_id')
    ->select('products.*', 'attachments.id as attachment_id')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();`

Comment: Use `distinct()`

Comment: it turned out same https://i.imgur.com/CpCg3A2.png